# relationship between solution of quintic in terms of $_{4}F_{3}$ hypergeometric function and theta functions

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, special-functions

There is one approach (Bring radical/method of differential resolvents) to the general solution to the quintic that gives the solution for a particular root $v\in\{v_{1},v_{2},v_{3},v_{4},v_{5}\}$ in terms of linear combinations of a $_{4}F_{3}$ hypergeometric function, and there's another which gives $v$ in terms of theta functions -- obviously for a given $v_{k}$, they must give the same value.

- Is there a general identity (or class of identities) which relates linear combinations of the $_{4}F_{3}$ hypergeometric function to the appropriate sums of theta functions in question? -- one could produce one directly above as indicated above, but I would be interested in knowing why such an identity arises or what its implications would be, or what generalizations of it might exist. (I am aware that Chapter 5 of Berndt's /Number Theory in the Spirit of Ramanujan/ is "The Connection Between Hypergeometric Function and Theta Function" -- but it's only about $_{2}F_{1}$s)
- Are their interpretations of such an identity in the context of analytic combinatorics?

Comment: Great question! Could you provide some references, that would be most welcomed! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @user5831 The following links provide related information: https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HypergeometricPFQ.html (under Examples->Applications), Weisstein, Eric W. "Quintic Equation." From MathWorld--A Wolfram Web Resource http://mathworld.wolfram.com/QuinticEquation.html, and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quintic_function#Beyond_radicals.

Comment: No answer :( I was so curious on this rip